# Why does the output of the mosfet differential pair connect to the gate of the pmos of a common source amplifier?

Tags: mosfet, differential

I'm told that a simple operational amplifier made from MOSFETs can be shown in the picture below.
M1 M2 M6 and M7 make a differential amplifier. M3 is used as the reference mosfet to create a current mirror and M8 and M5 is a common source amplifier.

Basically its two amplifiers and so gain is G = Gd * Gcs.

The problem at hand is that i'm not fully understanding why the output of the differential amplifier is connecting to the gate of the p mosfet M8.

For example the usual common source amplifiers that I have seen is that the Vin is at the gate of the nmos M5, this is the signal that is being amplified. The gate of mosfet M8 is usually a bias voltage to keep the mosfets in saturation, also  the current flowing through both mosfets is the same.

In the configuration shown the signal being amplified is put through the gate voltage of M8, which doesn't make sense to me.
The drain current and so the current through M8 and M5 is the same and  this is assigned by the current mirror, and so this sets the gain. However said above the gate voltage of the pmos in cs amplifiers i have seen has been a bias voltage to keep it in saturation. So it makes no sense to me how the voltage output of the differential amplifier is getting amplified from being connected to the gate voltage of M8.

Hopefully the problem comes across clearly.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: "M8 and M5 is the same" Not necessarily. If there is a load some current goes into that. You are also ignoring the output resistance of M5 and M8.

Comment: For small signals, the power rail at the top of the schematic stays at a constant voltage, so it behaves just like the ground rail at the bottom of the schematic. So, the two transistors m5 and m8 are connected drain-source in parallel.  It does not really matter which transistor gets it’s gate driven by the signal.

Comment: @user69795 is the mosfet M8 in the linear region?

Comment: M5 is NOT a common source amplifier. It, like M4, is a current source. M8 is the common source amplifier, so connecting the diffamp output to it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I think this was the clarification I needed, however, M8 would need to be in the saturated region for amplifying to work. and for a pmos the criteria |Vds| > |Vgs| - |Vt|. Therefore wouldn't the Vgs for M8 be very big so that the pmos is pushed into the linear region?